# How to get the Outstanding balance using debit credit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get the outstanding balance for all contractors and vendors using debit credit, but the problem is there are multiple document number so i cant relate them with debit-credit to become balance.

I tried relating the cdvno  but the problem is there were multiple entry so is there possible way to relate them with each other

```
SELECT b.amount,a.cdvno, a.debit, a.credit, a.Debit + a.Credit - b.amount 'balance'
    FROM cdvdtl a left join
         cdvhdr b
         on b.cdvno = a.cdvno and b.trantype = a.trantype
```

i want the result to be like this if possible with only 1 cdvno output

```
amount          cdvno           debit      credit      balance
15000.00    000-2016-02000009   0.00       15000.00 0.00
15000.00    000-2016-02000009   15000.00    0.00    0.00
```

but the result is like this

```
amount  cdvno              debit    credit  balance
596.64  000-2016-01000617   0.00    596.64  0.00
596.64  000-2016-01000617   0.00    6.03    -590.61
596.64  000-2016-01000617   602.67  0.00    6.03
```

sample data in my table1 cdvdtl
[cdvhdr debit credit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbT42.png)

Comment: please share your schema, sample data

Comment: schema ? dbo . sample data 339471 data rows

Comment: You should share the available fields that your models have in order to be able to help you after know the options we can use to relate them. That's call the schema of your database or for a specific table.

Comment: `How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example` https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your sample expected result should match your sample actual result - that would help clear up the confusion.  I *think* you want to `sum` the `credits` in a single row, and `sum` the debits in a single row (2 rows per cdvno), and show that value against the cdvhbr amount field.  If that's the case, let us know and we'd be happy to help...

Comment: thank you sgeddes that is actually i need to do to check if there is any payables in the data. any idea how  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, here's one solution using `union all` to separate the records and get 2 rows per `cdvno` with a `debit` balance and a `credit` balance.

```
select a.cdvno, a.debit, a.credit, a.credit + a.debit - coalesce(b.bamount,0)
from (
    select cdvno, debit, sum(credit) credit, trantype
    from cdvdtl  
    where debit = 0
    group by cdvno, debit, trantype
    union all
    select cdvno, sum(debit) debit, credit, trantype
    from cdvdtl  
    where credit = 0
    group by cdvno, credit, trantype
) a left join cdvhdr b
     on b.cdvno = a.cdvno and b.trantype = a.trantype
```

Comment: it works fine but i dont understand what happen ? how do you relate the two fields ?

Comment: Ok i think i understand what happen thank you for this bro works like magic

Comment: bro how can filter it with balance not equal to zero ? since it is not a table field name ?

Comment: @raphaelestranero - just add `where a.credit + a.debit - coalesce(b.bamount,0) <> 0` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the logic behind the [amount] column as it seems not following the math running on debit nor credit.

But one way to tickle your situation of scattering debit and credit could be using group by

```
    select amount, cdvno, sum(debit) as [debit], sum(credit) as [credit],sum(balance) as [balance] from [tablename] group by cdvno
```

Comment: bro i dont have field name balance. error on that thanks